# One iCloud account for multiple users

Tags: icloud

I have my own iPhone and iPad and my boys iPods on an iCloud account. I've since added my boys iPhones on the same account so that I can monitor and control their apps and purchases.

However I'm now getting calls and texts on my iPhone that are sent to them and when I send a text it shows as coming from their phones. 
Do I need to set up separate iCloud's to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From Apple's perspective, one Apple ID = one person. If you want to share that Apple ID, it also means that all those sharing that Apple ID will have access to all the same things (purchases, texts, emails, etc.)

You may want to look into iCloud's [Family Sharing](http://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/), which allows up to six Apple IDs to be designated as belonging to one family. That allows the family to  share each other’s iTunes, iBooks, and App Store purchases without needing to share an Apple ID.

Comment: To add to this: you can have the same Apple ID for iTunes and App Store purchases, while having a spectate one for iCloud (and iMessage, FaceTime, Calls on other Devices)

Comment: Good point by @IronCraftMan - I have three AppleID on most devices. One testing, one work, one personal. I use the personal one for mail, find my phone, app purchases and music subscriptions. That ID also is part of a family so that we can all share purchases and some calendars/reminder lists amongst the family.